# Solr search query is slow at first but quiet fast for later on same queries

Tags: java, solr, solrcloud

I am trying to figure out why my queries are extremely slow for around 1M documents and the server has around 8GB RAM. My query looks like this :

```
(indexType:msg && participantIds:4ac72a5a8a8d43339f8eaf2ff142a6fe && ((searchDescription:example*) || (searchSummary:example*)))|| (indexType:files && participantIds:4ac72a5a8a8d43339f8eaf2ff142a6fe && ((searchTitle:example*) || (searchDescription:example*)))|| (indexType:thread &&  groupType:1 && participantIds:4ac72a5a8a8d43339f8eaf2ff142a6fe && searchTitle:example*^5)|| (indexType:thread && (groupType:3 || (groupType:2 && participantIds:4ac72a5a8a8d43339f8eaf2ff142a6fe)) && searchTitle:example*)|| (indexType:member && (searchTitle:example*^3))
```

Previously, the query was OK and it provided a response around 500ms. But, later it took around 16-20sec to get the search result. From the above query, all the fields are indexed except the participantIds.  My question is :

How can I increase the performance of the above query?
Do I need to index the participantIds too?